# How to loop in function displaying output in select<tag>?

Tags: javascript, php

I've got a problem, I ihnk my function could handle 1 select, but inside in my option I was using loop but I don't why it doesn't work because I was using looping so it should work, it only work at once. Need some help

Here's my code:

```
<script>
      function getImage1(str) {


        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
          // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else { // code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {

          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

          }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getImage.php?no="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
      }

   </script>
```

===========Here's my code in PHP

```
<select  onchange="getImage1(this.value)" name="<?php echo $rowasa['pos_name'] ?>" style="height: 47px;">
        <option value='0' >Pls. Select <?php echo $rowasa['pos_name'] ?></option>
        <?php
        include('connection/connect.php');
        $dsds=$rowasa['posid'];
        $YearNow=Date('Y');
            $results = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM candidates,student,school_year,partylist where student.idno = candidates.idno AND school_year.syearid = candidates.syearid AND posid =:a AND candidates.partyid = partylist.partyid AND  school_year.from_year like $YearNow  ");

            $results->bindParam(':a', $dsds);
            $results->execute();
            for($i=0; $rows = $results->fetch(); $i++){
                            ?><!---$rows['candid'] . "," .-->
                    <option style="padding: 35px 50px 35px 80px; background:url('admin/candidates/images/<?php echo $rows['image']; ?>')  no-repeat scroll 5px 7px / 70px auto rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"  

                value="<?php echo $rows['candid'] . "-" ."&nbsp". $rows['lastname'] .",". "&nbsp". $rows['firstname'] ?>"> <?php echo $rows['lastname'] ?>,
                    <?php echo $rows['firstname'] ?>

                - <?php 
                        echo $rows['party_name']?></option>

                <?php

            }

        ?>

            </select>
            // here's the id
```

Comment: Where is your closing `}` for your `for($i=0; $rows = $results->fetch(); $i++){`? Also, why are you doing `for($i=0; $rows = $results->fetch(); $i++)` instead of simply `while($rows = $results->fetch())`, as you never use the `$i`, so it is unnecessary code.

Comment: why use `LIKE` why not just `from_year = '$YearNow'` or something like `YEAR(NOW())`